# No lines are visible in the Excel chart (xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers) despite adding data from an array (Date) and an array (Values) using .NewSeries

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am new to this forum and hope that I can describe my problem well.
My problem is to create an Excel macro that should generate a chart.

I am using the following code to insert a chart with data from a range in a worksheet, and it works very well.

```
    Set Rng = Sheets(ACTTab.Name).Range("H1:K" & CStr(DataRange.Count + 1))
    
    With Xhart.Chart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "WAO"
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = (WAODateStop + WAOTimeStop)
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = (WAODateStart + WAOTimeStart)
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        .SetSourceData Source:=Rng
    End With
```

Now I want to merge multiple ranges into one chart and insert this chart into a separate worksheet. The data ranges are located in separate charts and ideally should not be copied. The ranges also have different sizes (differing number of samples), but they are within the same time range.

I have learned from some forums that I can implement this as follows.

```
    TempValuesAWO = GetTempValues(TempRngAWO) ' Array(550.0, 500.0, 510.1, n) Double
    TempDateAWO = GetDateValues(TempRngAWO)   ' Array("2/9/2023  11:21:01 AM","2/9/2023  11:22:01 AM","2/9/2023  11:23:03 AM", n) Date

    With Xhart.Chart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Rejestracja temperatury"
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = DateTimeStop
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = DateTimeStart
        .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss"
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "AWO"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = TempValuesAWO  ' Array(550.0, 500.0, 510.1, n) Double
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = TempDateAWO ' Array("2/9/2023  11:21:01 AM","2/9/2023  11:22:01 AM","2/9/2023  11:23:03 AM", n) Date
    End With
```

[image: The result looks as follows]

Comment: Is it possible your axis limits are hiding the data?

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your prompt response. 

The code snippet contains sample data (Array(550.0, 500.0, 510.1, n)) that is only used to illustrate the structure. The chart in the figure was created with actual data that resides within the depicted range.

I have temporarily set a fixed limit for testing purposes.
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 600#
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0#
Unfortunately, it didn't work. However, I'm not sure if you are referring to this limit.

Comment: If you manually set both the chart axes to "auto" do you see your data?

Comment: @Tim The limits are set to "Auto" by default. I have verified this in the debugger. Therefore, the limits shown in the figure correspond to the automatically determined values.

Comment: If you change the chart type to have markers do you see the points?

Comment: @Tim I changed the "ChartType" to "xlXYScatterLines", but unfortunately, I don't see any lines or points.

Comment: I'd need a more-complete set of code to be able to do any testing...

Answer (score 0):

The solution involved converting the time axis into the Double format.

I have created a simplified example.
The example can be inserted into a macro module.
The following data must be inserted into Tabelle2 and Tabelle3:

```
Date/Time              | Zone 1 | Zone 2
02/09/2023 11:21:01 AM | 548.4  | 548.5
02/09/2023 11:22:01 AM | 549.6  | 546.9
02/09/2023 11:23:03 AM | 545.9  | 546.2

Date/Time              | Zone 1 | Zone 2
02/09/2023 12:48:01 PM | 543.4  | 542.2
02/09/2023 12:49:02 PM | 535.8  | 542.0
02/09/2023 12:50:01 PM | 542.7  | 541.9
02/09/2023 12:51:01 PM | 543.7  | 541.7
```

---

```
Public Sub CreateXYScatterChart()

    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    
    ' Diagramm erstellen
    Set chartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Width:=400, Top:=10, Height:=300)
    
    ' Daten in das Diagramm einfügen
    With chartObj.Chart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss"
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        
        AddSeriesCollection .SeriesCollection, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("A1:B4"), "AWO - "
        
        AddSeriesCollection .SeriesCollection, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle3").Range("A1:C5"), "LGO - "
    End With
End Sub

Sub AddSeriesCollection(ByRef XeriesCollection As SeriesCollection, ByRef tValues As Range, Prefix As String)
        'The function generates one or more Series from a Range object.
        
        Dim TempValues As Variant
        Dim SCCount As Integer
        Dim n1 As Integer
        
        TempValues = GetTempValues(tValues) 'Read the Range and store it in an array.

        'Generate Series.
        If (UBound(TempValues) > 1) Then
        
            For n1 = 2 To UBound(TempValues)
                
                XeriesCollection.NewSeries
                
                SCCount = XeriesCollection.Count
                
                XeriesCollection(SCCount).Name = Prefix & tValues.Cells(1, n1).Value
                XeriesCollection(SCCount).xValues = TempValues(1)
                XeriesCollection(SCCount).Values = TempValues(n1)
            Next
        End If
End Sub

Function GetTempValues(ByRef DiagRng As Range) As Variant
    'The function stores values from a Range object into a multidimensional array structured as follows:
    'tValues(1) = Array(CDlb("2/9/2023  11:21:01 AM"), CDlb("2/9/2023  11:22:01 AM"), CDlb("2/9/2023  11:23:03 AM"), CDlb(n))
    'tValues(2) = Array(550.0, 500.0, 510.1, n) Double
    'tValues(3) = Array(552.9, 501.0, 536.1, n) Double
    
    Dim n1, Sample As Integer
    Dim tValues() As Variant
    Dim tValue() As Double
    Dim tXValue() As Double 'Here, I changed the data type from Date to Double.
    'Dim tXValue() As Date
    
    'Determine the dimensions of the range and size the arrays accordingly.
    ReDim tValues(1 To DiagRng.Columns.Count)
    ReDim tXValue(1 To (DiagRng.Rows.Count - 1))
    ReDim tValue(1 To (DiagRng.Rows.Count - 1))
    
    'Create all necessary instances by copying.
    tValues(1) = tXValue
    
    For n1 = (LBound(tValues) + 1) To UBound(tValues)
        
        tValues(n1) = tValue
    Next

    'Transfer values from Range to the array.
    For Sample = 2 To (DiagRng.Rows.Count)
    
        For n1 = 1 To (DiagRng.Columns.Count)
            
            'Here, I explicitly convert all values to Double, so that the Date values are also in the Double format.
            tValues(n1)(Sample - 1) = CDbl(DiagRng.Cells(Sample, n1).Value)
            'tValues(n1)(Sample - 1) = DiagRng.Cells(Sample, n1).Value
        Next
    Next
    
    GetTempValues = tValues
End Function
```

Figure before and after the change.

[Bild1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If7SY.png)

[Bild2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXDU0.png)

Although this doesn't fully explain why the data is not displayed in the first figure, after making this change, it also works in the original code.